# PHP/HTML form post to email not posting data through

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

I can't get this HTML form to post the data to PHP. The mail comes through ok, and has the titles (i.e. `First Name:` or `Last Name:`) but the actual data submitted is blank. What could be wrong with it?

HTML FORM DATA:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="contact-form bottom">
                <a name="contact" class="more scrolly"></a>
                    <h2>We'll call you back!</h2>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="first" class="form-control" required placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="last" class="form-control" required placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" required placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select input type="text" name="debt" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Debt_Level">Debt Level</option>
                            <option value="-">-</option>
                            <option value="3000-5000">£3000-£5000</option>
                            <option value="6000-1000">£6000-£10,000</option>
                            <option value="11000+">£11,000+</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="occupancy" name="occupancy" class="form-control" required placeholder="Occupancy">
                        </div>                 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

PHP FORM DATA:

```
    <?php
// if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
if(!empty($_POST['first']) && !empty($_POST['last']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['purpose']) && !empty($_POST['amount']) && !empty($_POST['mortgage']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}


$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$debt = $_POST['debt'] ;
$occupancy = $_POST['occupancy'] ;

$email_from = 'trustmoney.co.uk';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Landing Page App'";
$email_body = "You have received a new application request from: $email \n".
"First Name:” $first “\n".
"Last Name: “$last “\n".
"Telephone: “$phone “\n".
"Email: “$email “\n".
"Debt Amount:”$debt “\n".
"Occupancy: “$occupancy “\n".
"\n".
"\n".
"Sent from trustmoney.co.uk to: “\n". 
$to = "matt.mckracken@trustmoney.co.uk \n";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from";
//$headers .= "Reply-To: $email ";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: Uh... What? Your first line `if(!empty ....) ` You are saying that if they **DO HAVE** a value, echo message that says they don't? - Secondly, even with the "validation", you still continue to execute the same code, meaning that whether or not there is any data, it will send a e-mail.

Comment: Please use debugging tools like var_dump, Firebug / Chrome developper to see if you have data in your POST.

Comment: Also, your string concatenation should not work without a concatenation operator... like ".".  You're in and out of quotes but no ".". Surprised you're not getting errors to report.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of you PHP doesn't really make sense. As @Epodax has pointed out you are checking if the input value aren't empty, then outputting an error saying they are but the email code is not even inside the IF function.

Your strings where you output the data aren't concatenated properly either.

```
$email_body = echo "You have received a new application request from:".$email."\n".
"First Name:".$first."\n".
"Last Name: "$last "\n". REST_OF_CODE_HERE
```

A better structure for managing your form validation would be breaking it down  for the user and returning them to the form with appropriate errors.

Something like

```
$_SESSION['POST_VARS'] = $_POST;
$errors = 0;

if(empty($_POST['first'])) {
    $_SESSION['errorFirst'] = "Cannot Be Blank, Contain Numbers or Special Characters";
    $errors++;
}
if(empty($_POST['last'])) {
    $_SESSION['errorLast'] = "Cannot Be Blank, Contain Numbers or Special Characters";
    $errors++;
}
```

Then count the errors

```
if($errors == 0) {

    // Your Submit Email Code

} else {

    require( "YOUR_FORM_HERE.php" );
}
```

Then you can just output the correct session variable in your form with the appropriate error displayed

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errorFirst'])) { echo "<div class=\"validateError\">" . $_SESSION['errorFirst'] . "</div>"; unset($_SESSION['errorFirst']); };
```

Also you can return the users original values to the form so they don't have to start from scratch.

```
<input type="text" name="first" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['POST_VARS']['first'])) { echo $_SESSION['POST_VARS']['first']; }; ?>"/>
```

Using this method you'll be able to output all the errors in your form to you users.

Comment: If this answered your question you should accept it

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your logic implementation.You Should use an || instead of && as follows

```
if(empty($_POST['first']) || empty($_POST['last']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['purpose']) || empty($_POST['amount']) || empty($_POST['mortgage']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
```